# How do I fix a java.lang.NumberFormatException: for String " " in my servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I keep running into the same error after trying to parse a String parameter I pulled from a corresponding jsp and make them into an integer and a float. In my web application I have java classes where the values I'm trying to parse are an integer and a float, but I can't seem to find a way to parse them and have my servlet work the way I'd like it to. Here's the code I used in my servlet:

```
        //get Parameter from newStudentPage.jsp
        String id = request.getParameter("stuId");
        String fName = request.getParameter("fName");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lName");
        String street = request.getParameter("street");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String state = request.getParameter("state");
        String zip = request.getParameter("zip");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String gpa = request.getParameter("gpa"); 

        int Zip = Integer.valueOf(zip);
        float GPA = Float.parseFloat(gpa);

        //Use RequestDispatcher to forward to jsp's
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("newStudentLoginPage.jsp");
        RequestDispatcher rd2 = request.getRequestDispatcher("newStudentSectionAddDrop.jsp");

        //Create Student object and fill with paramater data
        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setstuId(id);
        s2.setfName(fName);
        s2.setlName(lName);
        s2.setstreet(street);
        s2.setcity(city);
        s2.setstate(state);
        s2.setzip(Zip);
        s2.setemail(email);
        s2.setgpa(GPA);

        //Put Student object into Session
        HttpSession ses2 = request.getSession();
        ses2.setAttribute("s2", s2);           
        if(id.equals("")||fName.equals("")||lName.equals("")||street.equals("")||city.equals("")||state.equals("")||zip.equals("")||email.equals("")||gpa.equals("")){
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }else{
            rd2.forward(request, response);
        }
```

Can anyone please offer my some insight to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like either `zip` or `gpa` is blank or a space (since we don't have a stack trace, just a portion of the stack trace as your question title). As a result, parsing `""` or `" "` will be a problem. Either you need to do an empty check or make sure that any pages leading to this one require a zip and gpa.

Comment: I tried before using zip == 0 and gpa == 0 and neither worked in my if statement that checked for null values. I also tried to parse them using Integer.parseInt(zip) and Float.parseFloat(gpa) inside my if statement and that didn't work either. What other method should I use instead.

Answer (score 2):

One or all of these lines can cause the exception:

```
int Zip = Integer.valueOf(zip);
float GPA = Float.parseFloat(gpa);
```

You need to check if String zip or gpa can always be converted into a number. What if the user enters nothing, i.e `""`, `" "`or a `non-number` like seven777 ? Those conditions will cause a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 2):

You should catch the exception and do something, i.e. provide a default value, ask the user to enter a valid value, etc...

```
    Float floatGpa = null;
    try {
        floatGpa = Float.parseFloat(gpa);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //do something
    }
```